# How do I access files in main project directory when operating from Unit Test?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, system.io.directory

I'm creating a XAML application that can accept, as one input a path to a singular Excel file, and as a second input a path to directory holding multiple Excel files. Once these are specified, the application will compare all of the lists in the directory to the file specified as the first parameter.

```
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
{
    public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ExcelApp { get; set; }

    public void CompareLists(string pathToComparisonDirectory, string pathToMasterListFile)
    {
        ConvertExcelFileToCsv(pathToMasterListFile, "Results");
        string masterListFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pathToMasterListFile) + ".csv";

        string masterListLocation = System.IO.Path.Combine(
            "Results", masterListFileName);
        string destinationPath = System.IO.Path.Combine("Results", "Comparison Lists");
        WalkAndConvertExcelFiles(pathToComparisonDirectory, destinationPath);

        string[] resultsPaths = Directory.GetFiles(destinationPath);

        var masterLineItems = File.ReadAllLines(masterListLocation).Skip(3);

        var appraiserPropertiesPrimary = masterLineItems.Select(
            x => new { lastName = x[1], state = x[4], licenseNumber = x[6] });

        var appraiserPropertiesSecondary = masterLineItems.Select(
            x => new { firstName = x[0], lastName = x[1], state = x[4] });

        //foreach()
    }

    public void WalkAndConvertExcelFiles(string directoryPath, string destinationPath = null)
    {
       string[] comparisonListsPaths = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);
        var xcelFiles = comparisonListsPaths.Where(x => x.Contains(".xls"));

        foreach (var i in xcelFiles)
        {
            ConvertExcelFileToCsv(i, destinationPath);
        }
    }

    public void ConvertExcelFileToCsv(string filePath, string destinationPath = null)
    {
        string fileNameSansExt = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);

        if (fileNameSansExt.Contains("~"))
            return;

        ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);

        string saveDestination = System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath ?? "",
            fileNameSansExt + ".csv");

        if (!ConvertedFiles.Any(x => x == saveDestination))
            ConvertedFiles.Add(saveDestination);

        ExcelApp.Workbooks[1].SaveAs(saveDestination, XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows);
        ExcelApp.Workbooks[1].Close();
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that `Directory.GetFiles()` targets the directory that the test is being run from, while the Excel Interop `_Workbook.SaveAs()` method targets the directory of the actual XAML project. I want the project code to target its own directory when looking for the created files, rather than targeting the test project directory, as is dictated by the behavior of `Directory.GetFiles()`.

To preempt this being marked as duplicate, this question specifically refers to code within the project being tested, not the code in the test itself.

Here is my (incomplete, no asserts yet) unit test:

```
class TestSuite
{    
    public App app { get; set; }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CompareListsTest()
    {
        if (Application.Current == null)
            app = new App
            {
                ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown
            };
        else
            app = (App)Application.Current;

        var window = new MainWindow();

        string sourceDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "FilesToParse");
        var mockMasterList = Path.Combine(sourceDirectoryPath, @"Report 6.28.18.xlsx");

        var comparisonDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(sourceDirectoryPath, "ComparisonLists");

        window.CompareLists(comparisonDirectoryPath, mockMasterist);
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'd like to be able to test this tool under the most similar conditions to an actual use case as I can, and this issue is preventing me from doing so. Is there a way to specify that I want to iterate over the files I've created, rather than a similarly named directory in the test project's directory?

Comment: Why do you have `"Results"` hardcoded as destination path? What path do you expect it will have during Test and actual execution. Think about running your tests on Build machine.

Comment: @vendettamit Chalk that up to the tool still being in the building/testing phase.That functionality won't see the final release.

Comment: Then why not make it configurable? A method argument or property. Use TestContext.ResultDurectory in test and a %Temp% for real world.